# Sinch Nuget package not supported with VS 2010 and framework 4.0

Tags: sinch

When installing Nuget package of sinch I got the un-supported error on VS2010 and Framework 4.0

```html
PM> Install-Package Sinch.SMS
Installing 'Sinch.SMS 1.1.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Sinch.SMS 1.1.0.0'.
Adding 'Sinch.SMS 1.1.0.0' to DMMService.
Uninstalling 'Sinch.SMS 1.1.0.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Sinch.SMS 1.1.0.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Sinch.SMS 1.1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package doe
s not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Sinch.SMS
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
 
PM>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Right now we only support 4.5